# Showing error "Function create_function() is deprecated"

Tags: errors

we are getting a error after updating a php version to 7.2

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in
>   /customers/3/6/9/vakantiewoning-in-zuid-frankrijk.be/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/Tigerdesign/inc/init.php
>   on line 22
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already
>   sent in
>   /customers/3/6/9/vakantiewoning-in-zuid-frankrijk.be/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/includes/hooks.php
>   on line 258
>
> Notice: woocommerce_get_page_id is deprecated since version 3.0! Use
>   wc_get_page_id instead. in
>   /customers/3/6/9/vakantiewoning-in-zuid-frankrijk.be/httpd.www/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 3888
>
> Notice: WC_Cart::get_cart_url is deprecated since version 2.5! Use
>   wc_get_cart_url instead. in
>   /customers/3/6/9/vakantiewoning-in-zuid-frankrijk.be/httpd.www/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 3888

Comment: Look at the file path in the first error. The problem is with your theme. You will need to contact the theme developer. Based on that error, and the last two errors, your theme is out of date and has not been updated for newer versions of WooCommerce and PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Problem lies in your theme. It’s not compatible with PHP 7.2.

In this version the `create_function` is deprecated and you should use [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead.

So for example instead of something like this:

```
$callback = create_function('', 'echo "'.str_replace('"', '\"', $section['desc']).'";');
```

You should use this:

```
$callback = function() {
    echo str_replace('"', '\"', $section['desc']);
};
```