# PHP Error Backtrace / create_function deprecated

Tags: php

After installing PHP 7.2.10, the following error appeared:

> PHP Error Backtrace Backtrace from warning 'Function create_function()
>   is deprecated' at /var/www/site/data/www/site.org/wp-config.php 110:
>   /var/www/site/data/www/site.org/wp-load.php 37 calling require_once()
>   /var/www/site/data/www/site.org/wp-admin/admin.php 31 calling require_once()
>   /var/www/site/data/www/site.org/wp-admin/post.php 12 calling require_once()
>
> Total PHP Notices: 1 NOTICE: wp-config.php:110 - Function
>   create_function() is deprecated

How can this problem be solved?

Perhaps this is due to the fact that create_function deprecated in php 7.2

Here is what I found in my topic:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->print_meta_box_content_callback = create_function( '$post,$args', 'echo $args["args"];' );
    }
```

How do I fix my code so that it does not conflict with 7.2.0?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/324284/15605) and here [PHP-Net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

Comment: Thanks. that's what i found. Tell me, how can I fix this? `public function __construct() {
  $this->print_meta_box_content_callback = create_function( '$post,$args', 'echo $args["args"];' );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing error "Function create\_function() is deprecated"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324273/showing-error-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Comment: Did you read the answer in Charles' first link?

Comment: @JacobPeattie  I read, thanks to him I found where the error is. But I do not know how to rewrite the old function.

Comment: @MaratPetrov `$this->print_meta_box_content_callback = function( $post, $args ){ echo $args['args']; };`